# How to add 2 models at once in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django v1.11.10 I have 2 models: Article and Files. In one article there can be many files attached. With scheme below I can create Article in admin panel, and then create File with `<select>` options to choose what Article it is related.

But I want to create Article and at the same page add many File objects pressing "plus" button. Like dynamically. Is it possible?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class File(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    path = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_folder)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(File)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `InlineModelAdmin` [`TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

```
from . import models

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Don't forget to admin.site.register 
Ex. admin.site.registe(Author, AuthorAdmin)